# How to resubmit the same input in gradio when there is error

Tags: gradio

I have a gradio interface which takes audio (microphone recording) as input and translates on output. If there is an error on output , the user has to rerecord the voice once again. Is there a way to resubmit the recorded voice and other inputs

I tried to save inputs and resubmit the output without asking demo user to rerecord the voice. But seems gradio does not have a way to resubmit the voice for same user session.

Here is my gradio interface:
gr.Interface(fn=transform, description='', article='', inputs=[
gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath", label="Record"), outputs=[gr.File(label="Recorded")])

When there is an error in "transform" function, there is an error message in the output. I wanted to retry the same recorded audio as it succeeds if the audio is re uploaded. However how to make submit button to resubmit with same input without inputting the fields again.

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example which shows your problem?

Comment: Could you please suggest on this

Comment: Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have included sufficient explanation to understand the problem. How can I get an answer on this